# glreadpixel() not giving output

Tags: c++, opengl

Firstly thanks for giving your time.This is one of question which has a lot of answers but it does not work, here I am trying to take an example and let's see if we can solve this and maybe someone will get benefited again in future.

So the problem is we have glreadpixel() calling on a point on a circle,  which is drawn by bresenham function.

But the thing is its not even giving any value than 0,0,0 for RGB on changing the background colour of the window.

Here is the big code, enjoy experimenting. I have tried everything. By the way, I am developing n  macOS (OpenGL is hardware independent )

```
using namespace std;
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
int r = 40;
int flag = 0;
 int cordinates [50][3]=
{

    {50, 50} ,   //0 station
    {400, 450} ,  //1 station
    {750, 250}   //2 station
};
int matrix[50][50] = {

    {0,1,1},
    {1,0,1},
    {1,1,0}

};
int trains[50][50] = {

    {3,4,0,1,999},
    {11,1,1,2,999},
    {0,0,0,999}

};
int x,y;
int *x1, *y3, x2, y2;
int xx,yy,xxx,yyy,p,q,vertexcount,counter;
int xinc,xinc3,i,j,system_time,flag1,time_chekcer_cnt,dda =0;
char buf3[12],buf[12];
float tempx0,tempy0,tempx1,tempy1;
int train0 = 999 ;int start0,speed0,next0,nextx0,nexty0,final0 = 999 ;//999 signifies invalid
int train1 ,start1, speed1,next1,nextx1,nexty1,final1 = 999 ;//999 signifies invalid
int train2 ,start2, speed2,next2,final2 = 999 ;//999 signifies invalid
void init2D()
{
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0.0);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D (0.0, 900.0, 0.0, 900.0);
}
;
void bresenham_circle(const int h, const int k,const int r)
{
    int x=0,y=r,p=(3-(2*r));
    do{
        //Read pixel
        unsigned char  pixelub[3];
        //  glReadPixels(<#GLint x#>, <#GLint y#>, <#GLsizei width#>, <#GLsizei height#>, <#GLenum format#>, <#GLenum type#>, <#GLvoid *pixels#>)


        glPointSize(1);
        //draw two points
        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
         glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2i((h+x),(k+y));
        glEnd();
        //color detection start
        glReadPixels
        (
         (h+x),(k+y),
         1, 1,
         GLUT_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixelub
         );

        //print
        cout <<"reading pixel :  "<<(h+x)<<" "<<(k+y);
        printf("r: %u g: %u b: %u\n", pixelub[0], pixelub[1], pixelub[2]);
        cout << endl;
        //end
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
         glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2i((h+y),(k+x));
        glEnd();
         glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2i((h+y),(k-x));
        glEnd();
         glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2i((h+x),(k-y));
        glEnd();
         glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2i((h-x),(k-y));
        glEnd();
         glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2i((h-y),(k-x));
        glEnd();
         glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2i((h-y),(k+x));
        glEnd();
         glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2i((h-x),(k+y));

        glEnd();

        x++;

        if(p<0){

            p+= ((4*x)+6);


        }else {

            y--;
            p+=(4*(x-y)+10);

        }
    }
        while (x<=y);

}
void drawBitmapText(char *string,float x,float y,float z)
{
    char *c;
    glRasterPos3f(x, y,z);

    for (c=string; *c != NULL; c++)
    {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, *c);
    }
}
void systemtime(){

    sprintf(buf, "%d", system_time); // puts string into buffer
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    sprintf(buf3, "%d", system_time-1); // puts string into buffer

    if(system_time >1){
        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        drawBitmapText(buf3,200,200,0);
        glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        drawBitmapText(buf,200,200,0);
        system_time =system_time+1;

    }else {
        drawBitmapText(buf,200,200,0);
        system_time =system_time+1;
    }

};

void draw_pixel(int x, int y){
    glPointSize(5);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    cout << "\n THIS IS PRINTING X and Y :"<<x<<" & "<<y<<endl;
    glVertex2i(x, y);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
//bresenham ..... i vant DDA

void draw_dda( float *x0, float *y0, int x1, int y1,int speed) {
              //cout << "\n LOOPING FOR START CORDIANTES :  X0 and Y0 "<<*x0<<*y0<<endl;
              int dx = x1 - *x0;
              int dy = y1 - *y0;
              //GLfloat x1 = p1.x; GLfloat y1 = p1.y;
              GLfloat step = 0;
              if(abs(dx) > abs(dy)) {
                  step = abs(dx);
              } else {
                  step = abs(dy);
              }
              GLfloat xInc = dx/step;
              GLfloat yInc = dy/step;
    for (int speed_count = 0 ; speed_count < speed ; speed_count++){


                  glPointSize(5);
                  glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                  glBegin(GL_POINTS);
                  //cout << "\n THIS IS PRINTING X and Y :"<<xInc<<" & "<<yInc<<endl;
                  glVertex2i(*x0, *y0);

                  glEnd();

        int cy1 = *y0;
        int cx1 = *x0;
        //cout << "\n calling bresenham";
         glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        bresenham_circle(cx1, cy1, r);
        //cout << " \n" <<cx1<<" "<<cy1<<" "<<r;
        while (flag != 1){

            r--;
            //cout <<"\n r is "<<r<<endl;
            if (r == 0){
                flag = 1;

            }
        }
        r =40;flag= 0;

        *x0 = *x0+xInc;
        *y0 = *y0+yInc;
         glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        int cy = *y0;
        int cx = *x0;
        //cout << "\n calling bresenham";
        bresenham_circle(cx, cy, r);
        //cout << " \n" <<cx<<" "<<cy<<" "<<r;
        while (flag != 1){

            r--;
            //cout <<"\n r is "<<r<<endl;
            if (r == 0){
                flag = 1;

            }
        }
        r =40;flag= 0;
                  //cout << "\n THIS IS PRINTING X and Y :"<<xInc<<" & "<<yInc<<endl;

    }

}

void drawline(float *x0, float *y0, int x1, int y1)
{ cout << "\n LOOPING FOR START CORDIANTES :   ("<<*x0<<","<<*y0<<") To ("<<x1<<","<<y1<<")"<<endl;
    int dx, dy, p, x, y;

    dx=x1-*x0;
    dy=y1-*y0;

    x=*x0;
    y=*y0;

    p=2*dy-dx;
    //cout << "X and X1 "<<x<<x1<<endl;
    if   (x<x1)
    {
        if(p>=0)
        {
            draw_pixel(x,y);


            //cout << ">>>>>. Y INCREMENTED >>>>> "<<y<<endl;
            y=y+1;
            p=p+2*dy-2*dx;

        }
        else
        {   //cout << "\n >>>>>NOT  Y INCREMENTED >>>>> "<<y<<endl;
            draw_pixel(x,y);
            //cout << "X and Y "<<x<<y<<endl;
            p=p+2*dy;


        }
        x=x+1;
    }
    *x0=x;
    *y0=y;
    //cout << "\n X  "<<x<<" and Y "<<y<<endl;
    //cout << "\n X0 "<<*x0<<" and Y0 "<<*y0<<endl;
}

void display_ndots()
{glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPointSize(5);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    //draw two points
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {   xx = cordinates[i][0];
        yy = cordinates[i][1];
        glVertex2i(xx,yy);
        //printf("%i",xx);
    }
    glEnd();

    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    //draw a line


    glLineWidth(3);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for(counter = 0 ; counter < 3 ; counter ++){
        for (p = 0 ; p < 3 ; p ++){

            for (q = 0 ; q < 3 ; q ++){

                if( matrix[p][q] == 1){

                    xx = cordinates[p][0];
                    yy = cordinates[p][1];
                    xxx = cordinates[q][0];
                    yyy = cordinates[q][1];
                    glVertex2i(xx,yy);
                    glVertex2i(xxx,yyy);
                }

            }

        }

    }
    glEnd();

    systemtime();
    time_chekcer_cnt = 0;
    for(time_chekcer_cnt = 0 ; time_chekcer_cnt <10 ; time_chekcer_cnt ++){

        if (system_time == trains[time_chekcer_cnt][0]){

            switch (time_chekcer_cnt)
            {
                case 0:  printf("Trian number %i have been started  server time  is %i \n",time_chekcer_cnt,system_time);

                    /*Initializing Train Data*/
                    train0 = time_chekcer_cnt;
                    speed0 = trains[time_chekcer_cnt][1];
                    start0 = trains[time_chekcer_cnt][2];
                    cout<<"\n >>>>>>>>>>>>>"<<start0<<endl;
                    tempx0 = cordinates[start0][0];
                    tempy0 = cordinates[start0][1];
                    next0 = trains[time_chekcer_cnt][3];
                    nextx0 = cordinates[next0][0];
                    nexty0 = cordinates[next0][1];
                    ;
                    i=0;
                    while (trains[time_chekcer_cnt][i] != 999) {
                        i = i+1;
                    }

                    final0 = trains[time_chekcer_cnt][i-1];//999 signifies invalid
                    printf("\nfinal station is %i \n",final0);
                     //tempx01 = cordinates[start0][0]+10;
                     //tempy01 = cordinates[start0][1];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("Trian number %i have been started  server time  is %i \n",time_chekcer_cnt,system_time);

                    /*Initializing Train Data*/
                    train1 = time_chekcer_cnt;
                    speed1 = trains[time_chekcer_cnt][1];
                    start1 = trains[time_chekcer_cnt][2];
                    cout<<"\n >>>>>>>>>>>>>"<<start0<<endl;
                    tempx1 = cordinates[start0][0];
                    tempy1 = cordinates[start0][1];
                    next1 = trains[time_chekcer_cnt][3];
                    nextx1 = cordinates[next0][0];
                    nexty1 = cordinates[next0][1];
                    ;
                    i=0;
                    while (trains[time_chekcer_cnt][i] != 999) {
                        i = i+1;
                    }

                    final1 = trains[time_chekcer_cnt][i-1];//999 signifies invalid
                    printf("\nfinal station is %i \n",final0);
                    break;
                    //default: // code to be executed if n doesn't match any cases
            }
        }
    }

    if (train0 != 999){

        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

        draw_dda( &tempx0, &tempy0 ,nextx0, nexty0,speed0);
         cout << "Draving from corinates ("<<tempx0<<","<<tempy0<<") To ("<<nextx0<<","<<nexty0<<")"<<endl;


    }
    if (train1 != 999){

        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

        ///  cout << "original x and y are "<<nextx0<<" & "<<nexty0;
        draw_dda( &tempx1, &tempy1 ,nextx1, nexty1,speed1);
        cout << "Draving from corinates ("<<tempx0<<","<<tempy0<<") To ("<<nextx0<<","<<nexty0<<")"<<endl;
        // drawline( &tempx0, &tempy0 ,nextx0, nexty0);
        //draw_dda( &tempx01, &tempy01 ,nextx0+10, nexty0);
        // cout<<"After call by reference it is :"<<nextx0<<" & "<<nexty0;

    }
    /*bresenham_circle(100, 100, r);

        while (flag != 1){

            r--;
            cout <<"\n r is "<<r<<endl;
            if (r == 0){
                flag = 1;
            }
        }*/

    glFlush();
   glGetError();
}


void timlycall (int unused) {

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(1000, timlycall, 0);


}
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize (900, 900);
    glutInitWindowPosition (0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow ("points and lines");
    init2D();

    glutDisplayFunc(display_ndots);
    //glutDisplayFunc(init2D);
    glutTimerFunc(0, timlycall, 0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

---

### Please not macos have library GLUT but windows have GL

Update 1.0

OK folks we have made some progress :

- Using GLUT_RGB in glreadpixel() gives error code 1280 i.e. detected
  by method BDL have provided. Which stands for incorrect enumeration ,
  so use GL_RGB inside glreadpixel()
- Now one more interesting thing we have to tackle, i.e now GlReadPixel
  is giving `r:255 g: 255 b: 255` as output , i.e background color
  instead of color that must be yellow , because we are calling the
  function on point which lies on the circle that too after its
  painted.

Comment: GLUT is not the same as GL. Both are available on MacOS as well as on Windows.

Comment: Please try to remove as much as possible from your code in order to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE). For example, remove all the code in comments (unless relevant) and all other code not directly related to drawing the circle. Please also fix the indentation. Please check for OpenGL errors by calling `glGetError` **and checking the result**. glReadPixels should produce a GL_INVALID_ENUM because GLUT_RGB is not a valid parameter (GL_RGB is).

Comment: You are clearing the screen with [0,0,0]. Why would [255,255,255] be the background color? You really have to reduce your example code. Kick out everything that is not directly related to the circle or the readpixel problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a wrong enumeration to `glReadPixels`. `GLUT_RGB` is not the same as `GL_RGB` and may thus not be used for this function.

This would have been reported as a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error by `glGetError()`, but the error code is never checked. You should use something like:

```
GLenum error = glGetError();
if (error != GL_NO_ERROR)
    std::cout << "OpenGL error: " << error << std::endl;
```

Comment: thanks , but now its reading background value ... can you give any suggestion